# Can we find explicit equation of the curve stated in LMFDB by using its generating vector?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In LMFDB, equation of some curves are given however there are also those are not. My question is "Is it possible to find explicit equation of curves by using its generating vector?" I add link for you to see example.

[The curve that we have its generating vector](https://www.lmfdb.org/HigherGenus/C/Aut/2.3-1.0.3-3-3-3.1)

Comment: To those voting to close: I agree this question could be better worded, but I think it's a good question! The LMFDB stores data about certain families of curves, in a format that makes it completely not obvious how (or even if it's possible) to actually extract an equation for that curve. The question is whether we can extract such an equation from the given data.